# Arquivo em Formato MSG - Assinatura Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, assinatura

Tenho um arquivo em formato msg, se eu clico nele duas vezes ele abre no outlook com uma assinatura configurada.
Porém ele contém imagens, alguém sabe como faço para editar o local que carrega as imagens neste arquivo? pois tenho que colocá-las online no servidor para todos poderem visualizar.
Não sei como edito ele ou como altero para formato html por exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como, basta abrir o arquivo que está em formato msg, então ele será exibido em formato de mensagem no Outlook, após vai em arquivo/salvar e escolhe formato html. Após edita o arquivo que está em formato html, e altera o local das imagens, inserindo o endereço delas online. Após acessa a pasta de assinaturas do Outlook, `%appdata%\Microsoft\Assinaturas` e substitui alguma assinatura que contem neste local em formato html pelo novo arquivo.